# Regex for query entities

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regex able to differentiate substrings within a query. A practical example would be a query for a movie database, where the goal is to return the results:

```
# query 1
title:movie one year:2018 rating:10 
# query 2
year:2019 rating:20
```

For the first example, I want a regex able to identify the title, year and rating, which is *movie one*, *2018* and *10*, respectively.

I achieved a solution that is close but doesn't fully satisfy the requirements:

```
title:\w+
year:\w+
rating:\w+
```

This works for queries composed of single words (e.g. title:movie), but doesn't work for those with multiple entities (e.g. title:movie one). Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use non-capture groups to match the "labels" and then use capture groups to match all characters between the labels (instead of just word characters, so that you capture spaces, etc). For example:

```
import re

s = 'title:movie one year:2018 rating:10'

matches = re.match(r'(?:title:)(.*)?(?:year:)(.*)?(?:rating:)(.*)?', s).groups()
print(matches)
# ('movie one ', '2018 ', '10')
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
import re
string='Movie One'
pattern='[\w\s]*'
result=re.match(pattern,string)
print(result)
```

Result:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='Movie One'>
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the task

Comment: I was responding to this line: "This works for queries composed of single words (e.g. title:movie), but doesn't work for those with multiple entities (e.g. title:movie one). Is there a way I can accomplish this?"